# Use OneDrive in an application to store file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, onedrive

I'm developping an Silverlight application for Windows Phone 8.1 in C# with Visual Studio 2013.
I want to access Onedrive to store Data. I heard this is possible with Live SDK.
I've searched for how to connect my app to Onedivre, but nothing that ihave  tried work. It end with the exeption "Client null" when i try to sign in Onedrive.
Which code should i use to connect the user to Onedrive in my app ?
Thanks for your help.

PS: I'm new in c# language and developping app for Windows Phone (this my "true" first app by the way). Sorry for bad language.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the onedrive sample for windows phone 8.1
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-win

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry i was on holidays so couldn't answer earlier. But i will check that solution.